# Sum Case When with multiple tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a test query.

I need to join two tables (which I have been able to do), but then I want to find out how many instances there are of two criteria. One of the criteria comes from the first table, the other comes from the second table.

EX.
Table 1 - tb_Products
Table 2 - tb_Category

ProdCode is in both tables - we are using this to link the tables together

Description is in tb_Category

HOWEVER, we need the tb_Products table linked as it is the only table that has the date field needed.

I have the below. I have a syntax error and I am not even sure if I can do this with a join so would appreciate some help and recommendations please. There is no way around it though, need these joined together so I can count the instances and use a date filter.

```
1| SELECT Description, a.* FROM tb_Products AS a
2| JOIN tb_Category AS n on 
3| a. ProdCode = b. ProdCode
4| SUM(CASE WHEN ProdCode = '13' AND Description = 'Snack' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CatSnack
5| WHEN Date = '08/03/2022'
```

Expected Result:

```
CatSnack
0
```

Actual Result:
`SYNTAX ERROR`

Literally any help would be appreciated. I've been at this for ages! The SYNTAX error appears on line 4

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used.

Comment: Don't put space in `a.ProdCode` and `b.ProdCode`. You have alias `n` but then use `b.`. SUM calc should be in SELECT before FROM.

Comment: I don't know of any RDBMS that just says *Syntax Error* and nothing else.

Comment: Why is `SUM` after your FROM clause? It should be before. There are several other problems with your query. Look up a sample query with `conditional aggregation` to get a baseline for what you need.

Comment: Also for any field that appears in both tables use alias to avid ambiguity.

Comment: The table prefix should resolve ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax and format errors:  location of sum clause, missing group by for aggregation, bad alias for tb_category (n), and spaces between alias and fields (a.
ProdCode).

The snippet below fixes those issues.

```
SELECT 
  a.ProdCode,
  b.Description, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.ProdCode = '13' AND b.Description = 'Snack' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CatSnack
FROM 
  tb_Products AS a
JOIN 
  tb_Category AS b 
ON 
  a.ProdCode = b.ProdCode
WHEN 
  a.Date = '08/03/2022'
GROUP BY
  a.ProdCode,
  b.Description
```